# Scope of variables in PHP file passed to Smarty

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I would like to know why the array isn't updated with a string concatenation in the following example.

```
$scripts = array( "jquery.js","bootstrap.min.js",
               "jquery-jvectormap-1.0.min.js",
               "jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js",
               "protoFluid.js");

foreach($scripts as $script)
$script = "/scripts/".$script;                 

$smarty -> assign('scripts',$scripts);
```

I expected this code to, for example, change `$scripts[0]` from `jquery.js` into `/scripts/jquery.js`. However, the Smarty debug console shows the following.

```
Smarty_Variable Object (3)
->value = Array (5)
0 => "jquery.js"
1 => "bootstrap.min.js"
2 => "jquery-jvectormap-1.0.min.js"
3 => "jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js"
4 => "protoFluid.js"
->nocache = false
->scope = "Smarty root"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreach is working on a copy of the array, you have to do:

```
foreach($scripts as &$script)
    $script = "/scripts/".$script;
```

Comment: That's not entirely true; it doesn't work on a copy, the `$script` variable is copied when you attempt to modify it. Same result, but different reason.

Comment: Yes, but means $scripts is not going to be changed and it has nothing to do with smarty.

Comment: I'm not disputing that, I'm saying that the reason why it doesn't work is not because `foreach` works on a copy of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you still need the original array afterwards, you could use `array_map()` to create a modified copy:

```
$smarty->assign('scripts', array_map(function($script) {
    return "/scripts/$script";
}, $scripts));
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me that that in PHP a variable is copied when you attempt to modify it. That's an important point not to forget.